# ASP.Net Custom Button List Compound control for touch screen interface

Tags: asp.net, controls, touchscreen

I am developing an ASP.Net web app that needs to run in a Kiosk/Touch screen environment.
The existing ASP.Net web controls are not too touch-screen friendly as they seem better suited for a mouse/touchpad.

The hot potato dropped in my lap when the powers-that-be decided we need some sort of composite control similar to the ASP.Net Radio Button List, but instead of radio buttons I want the items to be displayed as large rubber buttons. The selected item's button needs to be indented for example or depict this graphically somehow.

I still need to have access to a selecteditem/ selectedvalue type property to determine what was selected...

What would be the best approach in achieving this? Creating a custom server control that overrides the radiobutton control or using a .Net control 'skin' file somehow that allows me to graphically alter a standard radio button list via CSS?

Your input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the existing control- [see here](http://tim.mackey.ie/HowToPresentARadiobuttonlistWithImages.aspx) for an example. See if that does what you require before considering extending an existing control or writing a custom one.